# How to Send an Email Django

Tags: django, smtp, office365

Previously, I was using SendGrid to serve emails using Django's `SMTP` backend, which worked perfectly fine. However, now I would like my project to use Microsoft Exchange. When I updated my `SMTP` configuration in `settings.py`, upon the submission of some form to be emailed, the page timesout when trying to reach the server: `TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out`.

settings.py

```
# E-Mail

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.microsoft365.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'username@domain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

views.py

```
 # Send email
 send_mail('!!New Mail!! ', content, 'noreply@domain.com', ['username@domain.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: Are you sure that your server can connect to your mail server via 587 port? Try to use telnet to connect to your mail server, make sure that your server can connect to mail server first

Comment: @ToanQuocHo I was able to connect to my mail server with telnet and also `nslookup` returned the correct `smtp`. Any other thoughts?

Comment: If you can connect via telnet with the credentials, so seem like nothing go wrong. Make sure that there is no configuration which overridden your email settings. I mean that we should make sure that when you call `send_email` the email settings setup properly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem when I used the correct SMTP port (25, 465, 587) for my particular mail server.

settings.py

```
EMAIL_PORT = 25
```